# jQuery get form which button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<form method="POST" action="" id ="formaclient" > 
  <input name="fullname">
  <input name="fullname1">
  <input name="fullname2">
  <input name="fullname3">
  <input class="btn-update">
</form>


$(".btn-update").click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).find("#formaclient").serialize();
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'demo/client_view_search_content.php',
        data: $("#formaclient").serialize(),
        success: function () {
            alert('Success!')
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Failure!')
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Something is wrong with

```
var data  = $(this).find("#formaclient").serialize();
```

I'm not getting data, how to change `var data  = $(this).find("#formaclient").serialize();` that I will get data from form ?

Comment: Your AJAX call has the correct format for the `data` value, so why are you not using the same call in your `var data = ...` statement?

Comment: `.find()` descends from the current element. Obviously, there are no elements within the button `$(this)`. Since you have the `id` of the form, why don't you just use it to locate the form? `$('#formaclient').serialize();` will do the trick. Also, remember that all IDs must be unique, so you should not worry about mixing up the forms :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to `find` elements with specific id values - a simple $('#formaclient') will do fine. It will also avoid the need to serialize the form data twice as your code attempts to do at present.

Your end result should look like this:

```js
$(".btn-update").click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var myData  = $('#formaclient').serialize(); 
    console.log(myData);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'demo/client_view_search_content.php',
        data: myData,
        success: function () {
            alert('Success!')
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Failure!')
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

As others have pointed out, trying to `find` an element will only search descendant elements from the one you start from (the button in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest()` instead of `find()`. find() will check for the children only. While `closest()` will check for the parents

```
 var data  = $(this).closest("#formaclient").serialize();
```

Since the id is unique, you can directly get the form like this,

```
var data  = $("#formaclient").serialize();
```

If you have multiple forms, use like this

```
 var data  = $(this).closest("form").serialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `.find()` wrong, because `.find()` searches for element descendants(children).

I think you should use `$("form#formaclient").serialize()` in order to serialize data.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **this** which is pointed to the **.btn-update** object. using .find() will check for the children of object only. use below to serialize the data :

```
var data = $("#formaclient").serialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

`.find()` descends from the current element. Obviously, since there are no elements within the button, you won't be able to find the form.

Since you have the `id` of the form, why don't you just use it to locate the form?

`$('#formaclient').serialize();` will do the trick.

Also, remember that all IDs must be unique, so you should not worry about mixing up the forms.